# Is my husband obligate to pay zakat al-fitr for his brother?

Tags: sadaqah-al-fitr

Is my husband obligate to pay zakat al-fitr for his brother who does menial jobs to survive?

I just want to ask my question and be guided

Comment: Salama nd welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. One liners hardly make good and answerable questions as the leave more open question than giving a hint for answering. To answer this we need more information for example is this brother living under the same roof and is your husband in charge for him. Under certain conditions one might be exempt from paying it. See [ask].